# Given a real matrix $M$, find the closest cross-correlation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, cross-correlation, convex

Say we have an arbitrary real matrix $M$. I am wondering if we can find a cross-correlation matrix that has the least square distance to $M$.

In other words,

$$\min_{A,B} \|M-A^TB \|^2_F $$
s.t.
$$diag(A^TA)=\mathbf{1} $$
$$diag(B^TB)=\mathbf{1} $$

All these matrices are real.
How can I perform this optimization? Is there a better way to formulate this objective?

I am also considering an easier case, where $B$ is already given, and its columns are of norm 1 (i.e. $diag(B^T B)=\mathbf{1} $).